# VSCode Android Emulator Restart: Error -32000

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

When I Restart my debugging on VSCode, I get this output:

```
Error -32000 received from application: Service protocol could not handle or find a handler for the requested method.
Restarted application in 1,009ms.
```

Also Hot Reload is giving this error:

```
Hot reload received invalid response: {type: Sentinel, kind: Collected, valueAsString: <collected>}
```

My environment is:

> Mac OS X 10.15 19A602
>
> VSCode 1.40.1
>
> Flutter v1.9.1+hotfix.6
>
> '[Android iOS Emulator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate)' 1.3.0 which is VSCode extension

When I start after stopping, the debugging it works but thats not a solution because its longer than restart or hot reload features.

Comment: Hi! Found any solution / reason for the issue?

Comment: @ahaaman not an actual solution. I have just realised that the problem occurs when I close flutter app on debug device. Right now, I'm debugging without closing (like swiping on recent apps or 'force stop' action) the app.

Comment: Just close the app and reinstall it again using the vs code. That would solve the error!

Answer (score 5):

Try `flutter clean`. This should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. What I did was

I clicked STOP

[image]

Then click Run without Debugging

now everything works fine :)